# using Cocoapods to install swift library

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I am no expert in Swift and a beginner but I was hoping for some help please.

I am using a template for an iOS app which uses an external library, [NVActivityIndicatorView](https://github.com/ninjaprox/NVActivityIndicatorView). In order to install this, I am using CocoaPods - navigating in Terminal into my directory containing the XCode Project and then using 'pod install'. I have checked the content of the podfile which does appear to contain the install reference (see attached image).[image]

Below is the output of 'pod install' too:-

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using BMSAnalyticsAPI (2.2.3)
Using BMSCore (2.3.5)
Using MessageKit (0.13.5)
Using NVActivityIndicatorView (4.4.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 3 dependencies from the Podfile and 4 total pods installed.
```

Nonetheless, when I then open my project in XCode v10.1 and I try to emulate my app, I receive a 'build failed' error with, "No such module 'NVActivityIndicatorView'"

I know this will be something obvious but as I'm new to Swift, I can't work out what. I did download the source code separately to try and problem solve this and dragged the source directory into my project in XCode but it didn't help.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Did you open default blue icon of your project or new created white with extension .xcworkspace

Comment: I opened the .xcodeproj file @RobertDresler

Comment: @thefragileomen yeah, you need to use the .xcworkspace file once you've used pod install in your project.

Comment: school boy error - if I open the .xcworkspace file, it works. Thanks @RobertDresler

Comment: @thefragileomen you can accept answer I wrote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using pods in your project you have to open the new created file with .xcworkspace extension instead of the old file with .xcodeproj extension

*it is that one with white icon*
[image]